# Cards of one suit or another (without replacement)

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Five cards are dealt without replacement from a standard deck of 52 cards. What is the probability that two are from one suit and three from a second?

Would it be $\dfrac{C(13,2)\cdot C(13,3)}{C(52,5)}$ ?

Comment: You need to account for the suits as well before you pick out 2 cards from that suit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

Number of ways to pick first suit=$\binom{4}{1}$,
Then number of ways to pick 2 cards from that suit = $\binom{13}{2}$

And so on...

Comment: Would it be $[C(4,1)\cdot C(3,1)\cdot C(13,2)\cdot C(13,3)]/C(52,5)$ then?

Comment: @interrogative yes that would be correct.

Comment: @interrogative Yes. In words: You want the probability for selecting a suit and three cards from that, and another suit and two cards from that, when you are selecting any five cards from a deck of fifty two.

$$\left.\binom 41\binom{13}3\binom 31\binom{13}2\middle/\binom{52}5\right.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, you have missed the terms which show how many ways to choose the suits. This would be the chance you got specifically two spades and three hearts.

Answer (score 0):

We have the total number of elementary events in this case is $\binom{52}{5}$ since we are choosing 5 cards from a deck of 52. Now, there are 2 conditions to fulfill, i.e., 2 cards from same suit, and the other three from another different suit.
There are 4 suits and 13 cards in each suit. $\therefore$ there are $\binom{13}{2}$ ways to choose 2 cards from each suit and 4.$\binom{13}{2}$ ways to choose them for all the 4 suits.
Now that we have got the number of ways to choose 2 cards, we compute similarly for the next 3 cards. However, this time we can only choose from 3 suits, as we have already chosen one suit for the 2 previous cards and can't use that again.
Now there are 3.$\binom{13}{3}$ ways to choose 3 cards from the 3 remaining suits. Combining the 2 results, there are 4.$\binom{13}{2}$.3.$\binom{13}{3}$ ways to choose the cards in desired way. Hence probability is $\frac{4.\binom{13}{2}.3.\binom{13}{3}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$